# General forming of a webpage with PHP and HTML

Tags: php, indexing, html

I am trying to run my webpage using HTML and PHP. I am doing this by making a reader.php and also an index.html file.
is this wrong? should all of this be in one file? If so should the file be .php or .html?
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: What do those files contain? What's their purpose? Can't really answer specifically other than saying that PHP and HTML can go side-by-side just fine.

Comment: really basic stuff. the reader identifies something entered in a form in index.html

Comment: Feel free to cut down your files to the bare-minimum (proof of concept) and post them here. You'll get much better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's fine if you are using with different function, such as :

```
<a href="reader.php"> go to reader.php from index.html </a>
```

Otherwise, if the reader.php and the index.html have a different function, then try to make it into one php file. I suggest you rename the index.html into index.php and load the reader.php
Here are some code :

filename: index.php

```
<html>
..... html tags and comment from index.html
<?php include('reader.php'); ?> <!--- include function to call the reader.php --->
......
</html>
```

Comment: exacty the thing i wanted... thanks a lot